# How to get the the URI path for javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo with parameters instead of values

Tags: java, rest

When I get the **UriInfo.getPath()**, it returns me **getFoo/12345/enable** (12345 is the id).
I want to get it as, **getFoo/id/enable** instead.

Is there a straightforward approach?  Or just parse the hell out of it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at UrlInfo.getPathSegments().  Might be easier than "parsing the hell out of it."  :)

https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.8/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getPathSegments()

Comment: Yeah, I already checked the segments, it just separates them, but still the list will have "getFoo", "12345" and "enable".  I need to get the parameter name of "12345" instead of the value.

Comment: Right, but super easy to replace the middle on that way was what I was getting at.  Not that using a regular expression is all that difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Just format your first result and replace numeric value with `id`.

```
String path = "getFoo/12345/enable";
System.out.println(path.replaceAll("\\d+", "id"));
```

Output:

```
getFoo/id/enable
```

Comment: I want to get the parameters as part of the link, so you can't just hardcode "id".  If the parameter is "otherId" then I cant use a simple replaceAll with "id".